# Tomcat v7.0 - http://localhost:8080/ works but my page doesnt

Tags: eclipse, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

Im new to JSF and I've been having the following issue:

I tried a simple example from a Tutorial, the famous Hello World thing...
But I keep getting 404 Errors.

I dont have any problems when accessing the localhost:8080 from my Eclipse (Indigo).
But it only works when I choose the option in the Tomcat server I created in Eclipse:
(double click in server) -> Server locations -> Use Tomcat installation

But when I try to connect to any page of my projects, I get 404 Error.

"description The requested resource is not available."

I really tried a lot of things, Ive been searching about it for days (yes, days) and nothing so far.

Does any one have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see your files in the tomcat/webapp directory? If not check your deploy path in eclipse server configuration. The deploy path is `<Tomcat>/webapp/` and you find your files under `<tomcat>/webapps/<yourprojectname>/xyz.xhtml` f.e.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: It seems like I've been doing a lot of wrong things.
I decided to start from 0, like I've never seen JSF in my life.
Leets see what happens! >.<
But thanks for the INFO. I cant see my files in the webapp directory. Ill pay attention about it!
Thanks thanks.